# Android Virtual Device OpenGL ES Failed to Initialize

Tags: android, flutter, android-virtual-device

I have been repeatedly trying to get an Android Virtual Device working with Hardware Acceleration on my laptop with a GTX 1650 Ti. The Android Virtual Device works with Swiftshaeder (running with `-gpu swiftshader_indirect`) with huge lag and running very slowly, but whenever I run it with the gpu, it gives me an error that OpenGLES failed to inialize. My Graphics Card should support OpenGLES, but I can not get it working.

The Error Message:

```
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsString! arbFound 0 listarbNull/empty 1 0 extFound 0 extNull/empty 1 0 remote 0
OpenGL Core Profile not supported.
getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date.

2. Erase and re-download the emulator ($ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator).

3. Try software rendering: Go to Extended Controls > Settings > Advanced tab and change "OpenGL ES renderer (requires restart)" to "Swiftshader".

Or, run emulator from command line with "-gpu swiftshader_indirect". 4. Please file an issue to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192727 and provide your complete CPU/GPU info plus OS and display setup.

crashhandler_die: fatal: OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date.

2. Erase and re-download the emulator ($ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator).

3. Try software rendering: Go to Extended Controls > Settings > Advanced tab and change "OpenGL ES renderer (requires restart)" to "Swiftshader".

Or, run emulator from command line with "-gpu swiftshader_indirect". 4. Please file an issue to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192727 and provide your complete CPU/GPU info plus OS and display setup.
```

Note: I know similar questions have been asked, but every solution is saying use Software Encoding. That is not what I am looking for, as Hardware Encoding should work. Software Encoding has terrible performance, and with a dedicated Graphics Card, there should be no issue for hardware encoding, especially with one as modern as the GTX 1650 Ti.

Comment: Any updates? I'm facing the same issue recently with Android emulator version 30.5.5.0. It starting with software GPU (which is very slow!!). I tried downgrading to serval older version (down to 29). Re-installed Android Studio. Nothing. I'm starting to suspect it somehow related to driver or windows updates

Comment: @sharonooo I have no idea why. My best buess is that my GPU isn't supported, which would be very unfortunate.